# Redirecionamento com htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Preciso fazer um direcionamento, quando o usuário acessar, https://www.dominio.com.br/portal/qualquercoisa seja direcionado para https://www.dominio.com.br/blog

É possível fazer isso com o .htaccess?

Segue código que possuo:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule .* / [R=200,L]
    RewriteRule ^portal/([a-z0-9\-]+)/$ ^blog/ [QSA]
</ifModule>
```

Obs: Dentro da pasta portal, já possuo um index.php direcionando para blog. Este .htaccess iria dentro desta pasta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do arquivo .htaccess que está dentro da pasta public_html/ de sua conta, basta adicionar a linha abaixo:

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domínio\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domínio\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domínio\.com\/pastaredirecionada\/" [R=301,L]
```

Este redirecionamento é mais complexo e indica (no exemplo acima) que o domínio “domínio.com.br” (sem aspas) irá redirecionar para “domínio.com/pastaredirecionada/” (sem aspas). Pode ser sem a pasta também.